# php gd extension

Tags: php, gd

I get a `Call to undefined function imagefontwidth()` error in my php file. I configured php with an extensions dir and enabled the gd library. But I still see the error.Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see GD loaded in the output of `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to phpinfo() and make sure everything was installed correctly. imagefontwidth() should be available since v4, so I do not think the version should be an issue. Other than that the only thing I could think of would be to reinstall the extensions.. Or:

**From PHP Manual**

> Check the php.ini file. Make sure the php_gd.dll isnt commented out.
>   Restarting apache should result in the image functions working.

Comment: I ran phpinfo() and found nothing with regards to extensions. I also uncommented 'php_gd.dll' and restarted apache, but still see the error.

Comment: This is odd. I ran php -m and the command returned gd as a compiled module. But phpinfo() does not show this module.

Comment: Here's what I get when I run 'php --ri gd':

gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.3
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.44
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0

Comment: Could there be an issue with apache web server? Which is what I am using to run php files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Initially I had uncommented the 'extension_dir = "ext"' line in php.ini. This did not work. I then put in a absolute path instead of 'ext'. So, the line now looks like 'extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"'. This works. I don't know why the default value wont work.

Comment: Did my answer lead you to this conclusion :D ?